# Items in SharePoint Tasks List disappeared

Tags: nintex-workflow

We have a Nintex flow developed on SharePoint List. Earlier, we had a list of 5K+ items in the task list. Currently, it is only displaying a few records. Please advise on this.

Note: we are using Nintex Workflow 2013

Thank you.